# Loading images in a multi-language multi-site configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

I have some custom components that specify images either in CSS or inline with relative paths:

```
<img src=\"images/loader.gif\">
```

The problem is that I have a multi-site configuration (I don't use any 3rd party extensions) where the site is defined to be a specific language. So when you go to the site say www.anothersite.com it is Spanish only. When you go to a url Joomla puts in the locale code according to what I setup in the Language manager. ie.

`www.anothersite.com/es/stuff`

This is a problem with my custom components as now any images try to resolve to:

`www.anothersite.com/es/images/loader.gif`

Which is incorrect as it is at:

`www.anothersite.com/images/loader.gif`

I have English sites as well in my multi-site configuration so it is important to resolve to: `www.anothersite.com/images/loader.gif` or at least something consistent.

I don't want to incorporate the language switcher as each site needs to be a dedicated language plus I doubt that changes anything. I can certainly add the language locale to my code but that is not a very elegant solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I had the same problem, adding this code to correct the <base> was the correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce your error, but you can remove the language code from the Language Filter Plugin by setting "Remove URL Language Code to YES. That will remove the `/es/` or `/en/` part from your URL.

[image: Language Filter Plugin]

You can also use absolute paths in the component with the `JURI::root()` string:

```
<img src="<?php echo 'JURI::root()'; ?>images/loader.gif">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of incorrect `<base>` tag value that is auto generated by Joomla in multi language setup when SEF and URL Rewriting are ON. You can fix it by removing the Joomla generated `<base>` tag and then adding a new one manually.

Open your template's index.php file, inside the `<head>` tag, after the `<jdoc:include type="head" />` add this code :

```
<?php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->base); ?>
<base href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>">
```

Tested with Joomla 3.6.5